# Gnome 3.14: disable background painting

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome3, desktop-customization

The question has been asked for older versions but it looks like none of the solutions work anymore:

In the GNOME desktop environment, how do I prevent it from drawing a desktop?

Background: I have a multi-monitor setup and want each monitor to show a different picture.
I have installed nitrogren but it can only paint below the GNOME desktop window.

The problem is that even when setting

```
org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'none'
```

it still insists on drawing the color.
I have also fiddled around with `org.gnome.desktop.background.primary-color` but setting it to an empty string or `none` only results in a black canvas.

I can totally understand that there's no GUI button for this, but not supporting it via dconf settings?!